# Unmodifiable lists in java

Tags: java, list

I'm confused at what would actually happen if I tried to modify a list in java which was set to be unmodifiable, I'm relatively new to Java and from what I can find where other people have asked a similar question it is that it is still modifiable, if so why is this?

Thank you.

Comment: It will thrown an Exception. Read the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29):

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows
>   modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.
>   Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified
>   list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via
>   its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

So it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Or from the source code:

```
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public E remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    //etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a List to be immutable.  Either it is mutable or it is not.  You can wrap a list with a wrapper which is immutable, however if you still have access to the underlying list you can modify it.

Comment: How are getting to know these information? You go through the source? ;)

Comment: @Octopus I have been through all the code, and I have written a functional collections library for one of my jobs.

Comment: You are really doing a great job. thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows
>   modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.
>   Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified
>   list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via
>   its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)